# Why would iTerm2 need to record the computer's screen?

Tags: iterm2, iterm

I finally installed iTerm2 on my Mac to improve my efficiency working in the terminal. Right out of the box it's been great. I got a popup saying "iTerm would like to record this computer's screen".

[image]

Why would iTerm need to record the computer screen?

Comment: Hello!  This seems like a question for Ask Different.  I would recommend moving the question over to those guys so you can get the best answer.

Comment: Hello @Salocor, it looks like that forum is for Apple only. iTerm is cross-platform. Even though only Mac offers the added security out of the box to get alerts when an application is trying to do something that seems suspicious, it's likely the app is trying to do the same thing on Linux and Windows and users just haven't realized it yet because the OS doesn't notify. So i'm more interested in the scope of iTerm than specific to Apple.

Comment: In OP's post, they said "I finally installed iTerm2 on my Mac", so I think this should go on the apple forum.  If they hadn't specified that, I agree, it would be ok to be on here.